# SQL Remove all characters between '[' ']' from entry

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I am rather new at SQL and need to remove all characters between '[' and ']' and leave the remaining string behind.

An example of what I am looking for is as follows:

```
[test]hi -> hi
```

I am assuming this is possible using a SQL command.

Comment: Are you asking how to transform data while `select`ing it, or do you want to update the data in-place?

Comment: can you please expected output and actual input

Comment: you should tag the dbms being used.

Comment: I would like to update the data in place.

Comment: VTC you have been asked to provide the dbms

Comment: I am using Sequel Pro to manage the database and then The MVC Framework Laravel that uses the database